# How to remove blank records returned from osql?

Tags: osql

I have a batch script which runs an sql query on multiple databases and appends the results to a .dat file. The script is adding 3 blank lines under the result from each database & also at the top of the file. Im using the below osql command to run the sql query.

osql -e -S %1-n -b -h-1 -w1000 -s","

I need to remove those blank spaces. Is there any osql options that i can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

try to change -w value, like -w4000 or -w8000 to set larger width of columns